# Getting empty object while POST request using fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side, fetch-api

I am a newbie in express/Node.js things. I tried to post a request containing the current user location(longitude and latitude using geolocation api).

/public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hey</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <button id="submit" class="click-btn">Submit my Location</button>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

/public/main.js

```
//navigating the user's current location using geolocation web api
const pos = {};
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (location) => {
      pos.latitude = location.coords.latitude;
      pos.longitude = location.coords.longitude;
    },
    (err) => console.log(err.message)
  );
} else {
  console.log("oops");
}

// handling submit location to send
// latitude, longitude to the server we created
const submit_button = document.getElementById("submit");

submit_button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: pos,
  };
  console.log(pos);
  fetch("/api", options);
});
```

/index.js

```
const { json } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listeninig...."));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" }));

app.post("/api", (request, response) => {
  console.log("I got request!");
  console.log(request.body);
});
```

Above index.js is server code. When I run index.js in the terminal I got the following output.

```
I got request!
{}
```

But in browser console,  `Object { latitude: 27.6430848, longitude: 84.115456 }` is showing. That means `pos` is not empty object. So why is it showing empty object in server side. Thank you in advance.

Comment: While that shouldn't be a problem here, note that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. Hoping that the properties will be set on `pos` by the time the button is clicked isn't a good approach. Better put the logic in a function that can be called from the event handler have it return (a promise that resolve to) the position.

Comment: A JavaScript object is not JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling I did console log inside event listener function and it's showing me pos object as I mentioned above. So I dont think its because of asyncronous property of `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` function.

Comment: That's why I said *"While that shouldn't be a problem here"*. It's still better to architect this differently so that you will never run into this issue when you change your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `stringify` the object you pass to `fetch`’s `body` parameter (in this case, in your `/public/main.js` file):

```
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  header: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(pos),
};
```

Comment: @SachinBhusal: You have to be more specific than that. "not working" is not a problem description that we can help you with.

Comment: @esqew Changing pos to `JSON.stringify(pos)` is still giving me empty object. And console log the response from the server like `fetch("/api", options)   .then((res) => console.log(res)).catch((err) => console.log(err.message));` is showing me error saying `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your body to a string before sending it to the server

```js
//navigating the user's current location using geolocation web api
const pos = {};
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (location) => {
      pos.latitude = location.coords.latitude;
      pos.longitude = location.coords.longitude;
    },
    (err) => console.log(err.message)
  );
} else {
  console.log("oops");
}

// handling submit location to send
// latitude, longitude to the server we created
const submit_button = document.getElementById("submit");

submit_button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(pos),
  };
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/api", options).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hey</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <button id="submit" class="click-btn">Submit my Location</button>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I  converted to a string as you said but not working.

Comment: Can you console log the response from the server?

Comment: ```fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", options).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });``` Like this?

Comment: No i got nothing

Comment: When i added .catch too to that statement like `fetch("/api", options)
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));` then I got error saying `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'.

Comment: You should provide a full address in `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api", options).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
  });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232286/discussion-between-sachin-bhusal-and-prathamesh-more).